# Changeset deployment Query

Tags: change-set

I have created a new custom setting C1 which will be referenced in our trigger A.

If I create a single changeset containing the metadata for C1 + A, will it cause issues during deployment ?.

Because till at this point, C1 custom setting will not exist.

Should I have to create a separate changeset (like predeployment changeset containing only the metadata for the custom setting C1) and another changeset containing the code ?

Has anyone faced my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends:

If you wrote your test methods properly to create a C1 record then you should be fine

If you trigger does not handle the fact that a C1 record does not exist then you will have issues